# Why is my variable not being defined?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function codeAddress(){
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    for (var i=1; i < 4; i++){
        var sAddress =document.getElementById("search_postcode" + i).value ;
        var loc=[];
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': sAddress}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
            {
                loc[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                loc[1]=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                document.getElementById("geo_lat" + i).value = loc[0];
                document.getElementById("geo_lon" + i).value = loc[1];
            }
            else
            {
                alert(status);
            }
        }); //end geocode function
    } //end for
} //end codeAddress function
```

Can anybody see why the variable i isnt getting set? The code works fine if I replace the i's with a number, but in the javascript error console, i isnt being defined so `var sAddress` is NULL.

---

### EDIT

The following code gives the correct answer when typed into the console when I put a breakpoint immediately after the defining of the 'for' loop:

[image]

Why would it not work in code but will work when manually typed into the console?

Comment: Maybe `i` is defined out of scope?

Comment: Even if it were defined out of scope, it wouldn't effect things.  Giovanni, I would do a `console.log('search_postcode' + i);` right before you set `sAddress` and see what's printed out.  I'm guessing you will see what you expect, but that ID doesn't exist in your DOM.

Comment: looks like the problem is that by the time the callback is called i will be 4

Comment: @Giovanni are you sure your function is called after the document has loaded?

Comment: Matthew has a point.. why dont u put var j= i; after var loc=[]; and in the geocode callback function, change i with j and console log i's and j's and see what you will see (console.log j inside geocode callback)

Comment: @MatthewMcveigh yes it is in a $(document).ready(function()

Answer (score 1):

If the exact code works with `i` replaced with numbers as you say then it looks like the  problem is that by the time your callback is called the captured `i` will be 4 (which if it doesn't cause your current issue will cause future issues)

Try this (copies `i` into a new scope):

```
function codeAddress(){
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(); 
    for (var i=1; i < 4; i++){
        var sAddress =document.getElementById("search_postcode" + i).value ;
        var loc=[];
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': sAddress}, (function(i){
            return function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                {
                    loc[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    loc[1]=results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    document.getElementById("geo_lat" + i).value = loc[0];
                    document.getElementById("geo_lon" + i).value = loc[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    alert(status);
                }
            };
        })(i)); //end geocode function
    } //end for
} //end codeAddress function
```

Otherwise if `document.getElementById("search_postcode" + i)` is returning null in your function and not in the console then it probably means your code is running before the document has loaded

Comment: progress! The value of i is now getting set so the variable sAddress is getting set as sy217ex (stepping through the code from the breakpoint I can see everything going on), but the status received from the geocoder is undefined so misses out the code in the if statement... Any ideas??

Answer (score 0):

check whether perticular Id **exists  or not** before invoking the **getElementById** method,

Comment: i'll suggest you to checkout the error using firebug or any other debuging tool, nad check out if the element is being properly added or not, and try to **alert document.getElementById("search_postcode" + i).value** too .. your code seems correct, something wrong may happen in your html page